# Adressing the ggplot-y-variable as condition parameter for dynamically suiting plot layers (here: adapting panel background color by using case_when)

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, parameters, conditional-statements

The following ggplot-code includes a `case_when` for changing the background color of the plot, depending on the type of spectral band variables.
The following code works principally fine: Changing the variable `CASETEST` between `bl`, `gr`, and `re` will switch the bgcolor accordingly between blue, green, and red.

```
BLUEBAND <- c(1,2,4,8,16,32,64)
GREENBAND <- c(1,3,9,27,81,243,729)
REDBAND <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
LEVEL99<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
BGR_DF <- as.data.frame(cbind(BLUEBAND,GREENBAND,REDBAND,LEVEL99))
str(BGR_DF)

BGRCOLORS <- c(#E6F1FF,#ECFFE6,#FFEBE6)

CASETEST <- "gr"

pltcolorcheck <- ggplot(BGR_DF, aes (x = LEVEL99, y = GREENBAND))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = case_when(
                                                CASETEST == "bl" ~ BGRCOLORS[1],
                                                CASETEST == "gr" ~ BGRCOLORS[2],
                                                CASETEST == "re" ~ BGRCOLORS[3]
)))

pltcolorcheck
```

Example with `CASETEST` = `gr` AND y-variable of ggplot being `GREENBAND`

[image]

Example with `CASETEST` = `re` AND y-variable of ggplot being `REDBAND`

[image]

**My issue** is now, that I dont want the `case_when`-conditions to be bound to a separate variable (here `CASETEST`), but rather ONLY to the y-variable which is currently given to `ggplot`. So for example, if the `ggplot`/`aes`-line contains `y = GREENBAND`, then the panel background should get the green color.

**My main questions** is, how to adress the `ggplot`-y-variable? Unfortunately I couldn't find any helpful posts. So, could anybody help me please?

Additional side question: How would I have to adapt `case_when` in order to give another color (e.g. gray), if the y-variable has any other name (except of `BLUEBAND`, `GREENBAND` or `REDBAND`)? Is there a term for say 'any-other-cases-than-listed-above'?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

1. Bring your data in long format
2. filter the band you want e.g. blue, green, red
3. then plot.

This code is a start you can modify in each direction:

```
library(tidyverse)
BGRCOLORS <- c("#E6F1FF","#ECFFE6","#FFEBE6")

long <- BGR_DF %>% 
    pivot_longer(
      cols = -LEVEL99
      ) %>% 
  filter(name=="BLUEBAND") 

  ggplot(long, aes(x = LEVEL99, y = value)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = lm) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = case_when(
      long$name == "BLUEBAND" ~ BGRCOLORS[1],
      long$name == "GREENBAND" ~ BGRCOLORS[2],
      long$name == "REDBAND" ~ BGRCOLORS[3]
    )))
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks, - I see I might have to deal some more with the LONG format :-) (also reffering to your response on my day-before-yesterday's question). My but in this case: Now the y-axis labels would be named 'value' no matter whether Green, Red or ... Of course I could subsequently overwrite the y-label manually depending on the band type. But then I had no win with respect to automatisation ... !? ... So I am wondering whether I could automatically generate the y-label by the filter name (in case of the example = BLUEBAND)??

Comment: Though this would be an alternative, of course, I would be still interested, whether I could adress the ggplot-y-variable directly according to my question, - also with respect to other purposes. Would also be helpful if anyone would tell me: "not possible this way".